# How to use AKS custom node config with terraform?

Tags: azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I need a k8s AKS cluster with custom node configuration as it is described in Azure docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/custom-node-configuration

More specifically I need `vm.max_map_count` config.

When using `az` command it can be done with `--linux-os-config` in command

`az aks create --name myAKS --resource-group myResGr --linux-os-config ./config.json`

How to configure `vm.max_map_count` using terraform and `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see, the AKS custom node is a preview feature, Terraform doesn't support this feature at this time. But if you don't mind, you can use the [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) to execute the CLI command in the Terraform to achieve it. This is a workaround, and currently, I think it's the only way to do it.